# Is 1/2 less than 1?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, ordered-fields

Prove that $\frac 12 \lt 1$

We're in the reals and we have the Field Axioms and Order Axiom. I know that for $x \lt y$, $y - x \gt 0$. However I think I'd be assuming what I;m trying to prove if I say that $1 -\frac 12 \gt 0$ and thus $1 \gt \frac 12$. How else can I go about this?

Comment: You could always just use the fact that Q is a subset of R, and then use the order relation on Q to prove it.

Comment: Use the order axioms involving addition and multiplication to reduce the problem to showing that $0 < 1$. That may be given as another axiom, or you can use the common axiom that $a \leq b$ and $c \geq 0$ imply $ac \leq bc$.

Comment: It would scare me to death to see a student of real-analysis try to bake a cake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $1/2 < 0$. Then $1 - 1/2 > 1 - 0 \implies 1/2 > 1 > 0$, a contradiction (if you don't know that $1>0$, prove that a square is always nonnegative and remember $1*1=1$).

Once you have that, then $1/2>0 \implies 1/2=1-1/2<1-0=1$.

Comment: I think the inequality you mean to write after the implication symbol is $0 > 1/2 > 1$.

Comment: I think not, @MichaelJoyce. I assume $1/2 < 0$ and conclude $1/2 > 0$, which is a contradiction too. It wasn't a mistake.

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely right, I misinterpreted which contradiction you were trying to obtain.  Very nice argument.

Comment: Doesn't this only show that $\frac 12 \gt 0$? How can you then conclude that $\frac 12 \lt 1$?

Comment: @flanger You reuse the same argument I first wrote. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume 
$$~~a > 0 ~~~~ \Rightarrow ~~~~ b + a > b~~\tag A$$ and that $$1/2 + 1/2 = 1 \tag B$$ then:

$$\begin{align}1 & > 1/2 &\text{to prove} \\
1/2 + 1/2  & > 1/2 &\text{by B}\\
1/2 &> 0 & \text{by A} \\
&\top &\text{quotient of positives is positive}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score -2):

2 = 1 + 1 > 1

So 1 = 2/2 > 1/2

Comment: How does the second part follow from the first?

Comment: How do you prove $x<y \implies x/2 < y/2$? The field axioms only say something when you multiply an inequality by a positive number, so you're pretty much assuming what you're trying to prove, I think...